# Why do some concurrent SSIS Execute SQL Tasks stall?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a large and complex SSIS project that I designed and built for a financial application for my company. A recent addition has resulted in behavior that I find puzzling and I am hoping that someone could provide an explanation for the behavior. Since the code is proprietary, I can't share the code here.

I have a sequence container that has 7 Execute SQL Tasks - one for each year - that are executed concurrently. Each task runs a SQL Server stored procedure for a date range and writes results using INSERT statements to a table partitioned by year. The number of rows inserted per day is roughly 250,000. The inserts are done with the TABLOCKX hint as shown below:

```
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO attr.securities WITH (TABLOCKX)
            (
                ...,
            )
            SELECT
                ...,
            FROM    #securities
        COMMIT
        CHECKPOINT
```

The table attr.securities has lock escalation policy defined as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [attr].[securities] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO)
```

The stored procedure processes each calendar day in the date range to compute the results to be inserted into the target table. Often the SSIS sequence container completes execution without a hitch. However, every now and then one or more of the Execute SQL tasks stalls. I can see that from the results of the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [year] = YEAR(asof_date),
    start_date = MIN(asof_date),
    end_date = MAX(asof_date)
FROM attr.securities WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY
    YEAR(asof_date)
ORDER BY
    [year]

year    start_date  end_date
2008    2008-09-30  2008-12-31
2009    2009-01-01  2009-03-21
2010    2010-01-01  2010-02-23
2011    2011-01-01  2011-02-19
2012    2012-01-01  2012-07-11
2013    2013-01-01  2013-07-09
2014    2014-01-01  2014-08-21
```

If the tasks were executing normally, the end_date values for each year would more or less be the same (with the exception of the year 2008 which processes fewer days).  When some Execute SQL Tasks stall, their end_date value lags behind. In the example, 2009-2011 have stalled. These tasks never complete. The only option is for me to stop the SSIS run and restart it or manually execute the Execute SQL Tasks in SSMS using a custom date range.

Why do the Execute SQL Tasks stall sometimes?
I have tried removing the TABLOCKX constraint but that makes things worse.
Is there some change I can make to ensure that the tasks complete on time?

Comment: You can try setting the **RetainSameConnection** property to false. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ml_aJK_l2M

Comment: I checked the property and found it was set to false.

Comment: On a quick look, why do you run them concurrently, wouldn't tablockX ensure that they have to run one after another anyway?

Comment: do you actually see any sql action in the activity monitor when stuff "lags out"?

Comment: There is a lot of processing that goes on with team tables in each SQL task. These would still execute concurrently even when the target table is locked. So, the performance is definitely better and the sequence container completes more quickly.

Comment: What activity monitor are you referring to? How do I access it?

Comment: I think you are referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/open-activity-monitor-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16. I tried it but it doesn't show anything. It is possible I don't have the permissions or the server is not configured to use the activity monitor.

Comment: That it's intermittent suggests to me that it could be data related, e.g.: a b-tree index reaches a critical point where it needs to rebalance and rewrite a large number of pages but is blocked by locks. Is the table a heap? What indexes does it have? Is the database using the simple or bulk-logged recovery models?

Comment: The table has a clustered primary key with 2 columns - a date and a security identifier. There are two non-clustered indexes defined for the table. The database uses a simple recovery model.